# How can you assign two key's to one command in this binds config file?

Tags: config

Below is a screenshot of the config file.
I can't figure out what language this is written in.
I want to have KEY_LEFT and KEY_H for COMMAND_UI_LEFT for example.
Doing KEY_LEFT, KEY_H did not work.
Thank you!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you try adding another line for COMMAND UI LEFT with the second key?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I tried that out and it seemed like only the duplicate that was the furthest down the list was used. So if I had duplicate A on line 1 and duplicate B on line 2, only the duplicate B would be used. And when switched places, duplicate A would be used. Weird.